# Workout first day of calendar month from user input

Tags: java, math, equation

I'm currently working on a project and I am wondering if anyone else can come up with an equation to work out first day of month for a calendar from user input.

The equation I'm using at the moment is ((dayOfWeek-1) - (day-1)%7)

Day of week is the number equivalent to the week day which the user inputs. Ex. - Sunday is 1, Monday is 2, Tuesday is 3 etc. I then subtract one to find the array m
number position (arrays start at 0 and count up).

Day is the day which they entered it is currently in the month. Ex. - 21, 8, 5. I then subtract again to find array number position. The array position is then modulus 7 finding the week day for the calendar to start at. Ex. If I entered day as 21 it would then be 21-1%7 which is 6.

The two numbers are then taken away from each other.

Example -
((4-1) - (21-1)%7)
3 - 20%7
3-6
Answer: -3
If I'm right it would mean September starts on a Thursday.

Can anybody think of another equation which would give the same answer that is different (smaller or bigger)?

NOTE: can not use classes such as Calendar.

Edit: 
As requested:

User input example

Year: 2016

Month: 9

Day: 21

Day of week: 4 (Thursday)

Output for calendar:

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSp1j.png)

Comment: Provide an example of a user input, and the output desired for that input.

Comment: Done now best I can. Circles and squares which may show in output example are dashes (-) to represent days from previous month upto starting date of current month.

Comment: Looks like you are provided the day of the week by the user.  What exactly are you trying to calculate then?

Comment: Trying to calculate day of week for the 1st of the month. The day of week they're entering is the week day of the week of the 21st.

Comment: You say `Sunday is 1, Monday is 2, Tuesday is 3 etc` and then later, in the user input, you say `Day of week: 4 (Thursday)`.  What happened to Wednesday?  If Sunday is 1, shouldn't Thursday be 5?

Comment: Yours doesn't seem to work as you need to take arrays into account. Arrays start at 0 (not 1) and if the user enters the week day as 2 for example, that will be Wednesday in an array compared to Monday if it wasn't. I've reworked yours and I got this: startDayOfMonth = ((day-1)%7)+(dayOfWeek-2); Edit: Even it is not working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Your current solution will not work in cases where the day in the week is small (like Sunday ['1']), as `((dayOfWeek-1) - (day-1)%7)` will produce zero or a negative number.

Assumptions:

- *daysInMonth = {1 ... 31}*
- *dayInWeek = {1 ... 7}*
- *daysInMonthReminder = {0 ... 6}*

  ```
   int daysInMonthReminder = dayInMonth%7;

    if(daysInMonthReminder >= dayInWeek) {

      daysInMonthReminder = daysInMonthReminder - dayInWeek;

      dayInWeek = 7;

  }

  return ((dayInWeek - daysInMonthReminder)%7) + 1;
  ```

Comment: Let's say I put the year as 2016, month as September (9), day as 21st and day of week as day 4. I then use my equation (dayofweek -1) - ((day-1) %7) which is (4-1)-((21-1)%7 which is -3. I then count back from Saturday inclusive as it is -3 which is Thursday (Sat -2, Friday -1, Thursday 0) which then tells me the first day of the month is Thursday. Outputting - http://puu.sh/sF9yS/d94a540819.png

Comment: 21%7 = 0. So the answer will be that the 1st in September is Wednesday.

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to add 1 to the answer, as there is no zero day in month. Edited.

Comment: I've found your way of working it out works however I don't believe you need to add the one in the final return. Thanks for the help, exactly what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstDayInMonth {
    final static String [] daysOfWeek = {
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
    };
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
        int dayInMonth = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int dayInWeek = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int firstDayinMonth =(dayInWeek-dayInMonth%7)>=0?dayInWeek-dayInMonth%7:7+(dayInWeek-dayInMonth%7);
        System.out.println("The first day of the month is: " + daysOfWeek[firstDayinMonth]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting another way! :)